# Navigation Failed. Cannot Locate Resource for ModernTab WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, modern-ui

I am using [ModernUI](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui) in my application. In the code below, I have a link "General" in `ModernTab` which is inside a window `PriceSettingsView` in a project `PriceSettingsUI`. When I run this application the `PriceSettingsView` window is shown and the link "General" is also working fine, but when I use `PriceSettingsView` in another project (calling from menu click event), the `PriceSettingView` window is showing up but the "General" link displays the following error message:

```
Navigation Failed. Cannot locate resource
```

Can someone please suggest why it is not working when calling the view from another project? Is something wrong with the source attribute when calling the view from another project?

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="PriceSettingsUI.PriceSettingsView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
         Style="{StaticResource EmptyWindow}" Title="PriceSettingsView" Height="700" Width="900">
    <Border Margin="0,5,0,0" BorderBrush="{StaticResource Accent}" BorderThickness="1">
        <mui:ModernTab>
            <mui:ModernTab.Links>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="General" Source="/Views/GeneralSettings.xaml"/>
            </mui:ModernTab.Links>
        </mui:ModernTab>
    </Border>
</mui:ModernWindow>
```

**Error Message:**

[image]

Please let me if anyone needs additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, when I use "PriceSettingsView" in another project (calling from menu click event) PriceSettingView window is showing up but link "General" giving error message as "Navigation Failed. Cannot locate resource".

You provide a URI for `GeneralSettings` that is relative to the **current** project. In the original project `A`, the `Views` folder exists and contains the `GeneralSettings` view, but when you use `PriceSettingsView` in another project `B`, there neither the folder nor the view are present and therefore the view cannot be resolved.

You have to specify the URI to `GeneralSettings` relative to the assembly that contains it and **reference** the corresponding project. Specify the referenced assembly in the URI, for example:

```
<mui:Link DisplayName="General" Source="/PriceSettingsUI;component/Views/GeneralSettings.xaml"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked for me. I also looked at more information about referencing namespaces and found the link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf